# Start network service at boot time on CentOS

Tags: ssh, networking, centos, services

I've recently reinstalled CentOS onto a computer of mine. I have OpenSSH Server on it now, as did I before I reinstalled the operating system.

Here's the difference: Before, SSH started without even having to login to an account. Now, it seems like I have to login to an account on the machine before being able to remotely connect via SSH.

Can anyone help? I tried using `chkconfig`, but that didn't appear to do anything differently.

Comment: Does your computer connect via wireless? Perhaps managed by gnome-network-manager ?

Comment: @shutupsquare - yes, actually that's the only difference. This install it's wireless, before it was a wired internet connection. I am still connecting from another computer on the network though. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: answered below pal.

Comment: @DannyF247 if you go to network manager on your desktop session and edit the wireless connection, is the checkbox "available for all users" checked? It might be needed for your purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wirless will be managed by Gnome Network manager, this will only start at login, You would be much better using wpa_supplicant to start your wireless at init. There is a nice tutorial [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/WpaSupplicant)

Comment: Firstly, thanks. I did that all successfully, except `Edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`. There were no existing files in `/network-scripts/` that ended with `eth0`, `eth1`, or `wlan0` (I need `wlan0` in my case). Any help?

Comment: If there is none just create it for your interface.

Comment: Alright, done. Still not connecting - when I ping it returns destination host unreachable. Is there any way I can "debug" this and see if its giving any error at startup?

Comment: What runlevel do you start in, do you boot straight to GUI login?

Comment: Anyways you need to paste me the output of dmesg tail the last 100 lines

Comment: I suppose, I never edited anything like this. It just comes on, then gives me the GUI to login.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4346/discussion-between-shutupsquare-and-dannyf247)

Comment: Alright thanks or all the help, and I finally figured out what was wrong. As tripledes commented to the OP, I needed to check the "Available for all users" box. I appreciate both your guyses help!