# Unable to make sshd start at boot time on centos 6.4 . It starts ONLY after I login from console

Tags: networking, centos, sshd

I have installed centos 6.4 on a desktop and wanted to access it mostly remotely. For this, I tried http://www.serverschool.com/server-configuration/3-ways-to-configure-services-to-start-at-boot-in-centos-part-1/
That didn't work - so tried [Start network service at boot time on CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44461/start-network-service-at-boot-time-on-centos) because my desktop is also on wlan. That didn't work. So now I am stuck. Any inputs appreciated on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: You can use `ntsysv` command to enable `ssh` service at startup

Comment: Thanks the problem (perhaps) is not that sshd is not started. The problem is that wlan card is not up until I login. I am not sure on how to confirm this though.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the ifcfg for this interface. For example, using wlan0.

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlan0`

Verify that the ONBOOT selection is enabled.

```
ONBOOT="yes"
```

Configure services to run at boot

```
chkconfig messagebus off
chkconfig wpa_supplicant off
chkconfig NetworkManager off
chkconfig network on
```

Reference [link](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/WpaSupplicant)

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the link. Now the machine hangs on booting. Here is what I did 1. Looked at /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlan0. Could not find it.Created one file with ifcfg-wlan0 and added ONBOOT-"yes" I did do iwconfig and it reported the wireless card fine. Then I just did vi /etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant and added interfaces = -iwlan0. I did not go to the next step of editing wpa_supplicant.conf since I did not know what to put it in psk="NETWORKPSK". I did do all the chkconfig that were mentioned and rebooted. Now the machine hangs. Is there a way to troubleshoot this now?

Comment: use `ONBOOT="yes"` instead of `ONBOOT-"yes"`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the message I did do ONBOOT="yes". So now this is what I have done. Created ifcfg-wlan with ONBOOT="yes". Then vi /etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant and added interfaces = -iwlan0. Then configured the wpa_supplicant.confg with correct PSK/ssid. Then did the chkconfig. Reboot. Nothing.

Comment: Then configured the wpa_supplicant.conf as on http://linuxdo.blogspot.in/2012/06/using-wifi-just-from-linux-terminal.html. When I do this wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/root/linuxdo.conf I get "Trying to associate with 00:8e:f2:5d:23:6c (SSID='CorrectSSID' freq=2442 MHz)
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:8e:f2:5d:23:6c reason=0
Associated with 00:8e:f2:5d:23:6c
WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:8e:f2:5d:23:6c [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:8e:f2:5d:23:6c completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC - dropping packet" .

Comment: So ultimately it seems that there is a problem in connecting to the wireless card via wpa_supplicant but no issue with network manager (which I presume does not use wpa_supplicant). I don't know if this can be discussed any longer in this forum but just wanted to put it out there. Thanks

Comment: Turns out that the issue was resolved already in the thread mentioned in the question. I just didn't see the last part in this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44461/start-network- service-at-boot-time-on-centos. If gnome network manager is configured as available for all users and connect automatically, there is no need to login via GUI. I have configured to login via GUI instead of console.That solved the issue.